# Python requests to login website behind captcha

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, python-requests

I want to log in an website https://eokulyd.meb.gov.tr/ and read some html from that.

But the website has an control image, user must write number which is in that image.

I know requests has Session class that allow us to log in websites, But when I use requests I cant take that control image.

I think that image is loading by JavaScript when website is opening.

Is there any way to use requests or should i use selenium? If I should use selenium, is there any way to use selenium while log in, and then use requests?

Comment: You're trying to get around a captcha by some automation? That's exactly what the captcha is there to prevent.

Comment: you probably need something with a real browser that executs java script like for example selenium.
I think you could be able to extract cookies from selenium, though I'm not 100% sure.
If you are able to extract cookies, then you can pass the session cookies and others to requests and continue from there.

Comment: Yes you can absolutely pass selenium cookies to requests, I've done it many times.

Comment: @pguardiario can you share a code example or a source about passing selenium cookies to requests?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's something along the lines of:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.cookies.update(driver.getCookies())
```

https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/getCookies.html